LXC (Proxmox) container with slow web server performance
I'm running Proxmox 8.2.4 on Debian 12 on a dual Xeon 4309Y (128 GB RAM/1 TB SSD) system and experiencing extremely bad web performance on my first container when I access that container externally.
The speed is great when I access the container directly from the Proxmox host, so I suspect something is wrong in my network bridging. It happens with both nginx and Apache, so either I'm missing something that both of them need in terms of optimizing for containerization or the issue lies elsewhere.
I configured a Debian 12 LXC container with 12 cores/32 GB RAM/64 GB SSD that performs as expected -- just 50 points off of a native per core speed on Geekbench 6. It has two virtual network cards connected to a local bridge vmbr0 (10.0.0.2) and one that connects to vmbr1 (static IP xx.xx.xx.64). The container has a static IP of xx.xx.xx.65 with the .64 bridge's IP as its gateway. The datacenter routed a /29 range statically to the Proxmox host's primary IP and then I sort things out with those IPs within my network configuration.
Ookla Speedtest's has essentially no sign of overhead going between the host and the container and Proxmox doesn't show the system under any strain at all, however compared to a similarly configured bare metal NGINX server in the same datacenter, I'm seeing a 7x-10x slowdown connecting to the container. While ab -n 10000 -c 100 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H can complete in about 10 seconds with 999 requests per second on the bare metal server, it takes 11 minutes and can only do 14 requests per second connecting to the container.  (The total time per request is actually faster on the container, it just can't seem to sustain a load.)
Here's my host interfaces configuration:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno8303
iface eno8303 inet manual

auto eno8403
iface eno8403 inet manual

iface ens3f0np0 inet manual

iface ens3f1np1 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.94/30
        gateway xx.xx.xx.93
        bond-slaves eno8303 eno8403
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-mode 802.3ad
        bond-xmit hash-policy layer2+3
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
        dns-search hostingdomaingoeshere.com

    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # add this line

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -F
    post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1


auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.64/29
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

    up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/vmbr1/proxy_arp

Here's the container's network configuration:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.65/29
        gateway xx.xx.xx.64

        up ip addr add xx.xx.xx.66/32 dev eth1
        up ip addr add xx.xx.xx.67/32 dev eth1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.2/24


Why that many IPs? Why is there proxy-arp? Can you try without it, and with simplest configuration at all (just one NIC and one IP address on it)? // What's about DNS? How quickly it happens in the container?

@NikitaKipriyanov the three static IPs are for future use for DNS serving -- it's meant to be a virtual hosting environment eventually. I tried it without the "internal" network NIC and it didn't seem to help. As to proxy-arp, I was under the impression I needed that to redirect from the host server's IP to the container's IP for routing. Maybe I don't?

It seems like a classic netcup/hetzner setup to me. How many cores are assigned to the container? Also, I would like to know the amount of RAM and the overall RAM usage. Generally, only the network part is shown.

@djdomi I wasn’t trying to copy Hetzner, but I guess if it works! I gave the container 12 cores (the system has 16 real/32 logical cores) and 32 GB out of the total of 128 GB of RAM. The container is using about 6% of its RAM.

Why having everything in a single container? The whole idea of containers is to separate services. Even with "thick" LXC containers like PVE has, it's sensible. Also, why doing it now? Start simple. Get something working, then go on making other container, with another IP, for DNS. And so on. Also you don't need proxy-arp for doing simple routing thing. The other network configuration bits doesn't call for one, and even if did, I'd suggest to get rid of it; you'd have to have very strong reason to use it. // I don't think it's performance issue. 32 GB is a lot, 12 cores is too.

What is the goal you want to achieve with this? My web container for both MediaWiki and WordPress has only 1 core and less than 2GB of RAM. I think there might be something wrong with the overall interaction. please split your setup or explain why you put all in one? I use nginx on the host and use 10/8 for the internal communication.

You have multiple IP addresses on the same lan - what are you doing to prevent asymmetric routing? Try removing the additional addresses and running your test again.

@NikitaKipriyanov don't I need proxy-arp if the host/server has that whole range of IP addresses statically routed to it and the containers need to respond to them?

@NikitaKipriyanov As to the size, that's for testing purposes -- I wanted to compare how it was doing to the bare metal hosting server, so I tried to give the container a similar configuration to the server it is replacing. I planned to bring that down.

@symcbean Those other IPs were ones I planned to assign to virtual hosts. I'm not doing anything to prevent asymmetric routing -- hadn't even thought of that. Do you have a recommendation? Thanks!

Don't assign multiple addresses on the same lan to a single host.

@symcbean so I'm hoping to do virtual hosting on this server. Trying to do it manually rather than using WHM/cPanel, but with WHM, I'd assign a whole pool of IPs I could divvy out to virtual hosts and DNS. My goal is to assign one of the IPs to BIND and another few to various web server virtual hosts. How do I accomplish that without assigning multiple IP addresses to the container?

Why do you think you need you need multiple IP addresses for "virtual hosting"? Websites have never needed unique IP addresses for HTTP, and not needed unique addresses for HTTPS for over 25 years.

@symcbean usually, when I setup a hosting environment I'll give it 3 IP addresses -- two for BIND (I know that's sort of cheating) and one for Apache. Occasionally, someone will want their site hosted with their own IP address, which is where others can come in handy...

You really do not want to hear my response to that.

@symcbean Go for it. Although since I've done this (and it isn't uncommon amongst hosts), I'm still curious why it isn't working on this particular system.

@symcbean For what it is worth, though, I did disable the other IPs and didn't improve the situation...

start simple. Create a new container, one NIC, one address in it, no tricks like proxy-arp or whatever, see if that works normally. // I've used Proxmox's LXC containers a lot, and never happened to see such problems. You definitely are trying to do something too complex from the start. Don't do it. And, you definitely don't need additional addresses in that container. You want DNS servers? Create another container for them, that's it.

@NikitaKipriyanov here's the bizarre result: I created the container and after it briefly exhibiting the same performance issues as the first container, both containers are now running close to exactly what I'd expect. That's good, but leaves me troubled, since I can't explain why the second container somehow helped resolve issues with the first.
